# color a text line in a code {lstlisting}

Tags: listings, color

I try to use the package `xcolor` into a `lstlisting` code as follows:

```
\begin{lstlisting}

\color{red}{text...}

\end{lstlisting}
```

but I can't color the "text..." comments.

Someone could help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to write code from a programming language? What programming language?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`lstlisting` is a verbatim environment, so it is designed to print exactly what you write in it, not evaluating any of the macros inside it. However, you can define special delimiters for bits of code that *should* be evaluated, by using `escapeinside={<opening delim>}{<closing delim>}` in `\lstset`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{escapeinside={<@}{@>}}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
This is normal text.
<@\textcolor{red}{red text}@>
More.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The red text is not in monospaced font. You might want to use `\texttt{\textcolor{red}{red text}`. (Ideally in verbatim instead of lstlisting - to have matching fonts.)

Comment: @JanineDaum This type of escaping won't work in the `verbatim` environment, but you can of course make `listings` use the typewriter font by saying `basicstyle=\ttfamily` in `\lstset`. Panichi didn't say anything about what kind of settings he was using for his listings, which is probably why I didn't add any other settings. For the example in the post, adding `columns=flexible` or `columns=fullflexible` would make the letter spacing more similar to the red text.

Comment: It would of course have to go outside of \verb, like`\verb+This is normal text, +\texttt{\textcolor{red}{red text, }}\verb+more.+`

Comment: Torbjorn, good idea of having `listings` use `\ttfamily`!

Comment: What if the code I want to have with different color spans over multiple lines?

Comment: @Andry You might have to repeat the instructions for each line. If that's not good enough, I suggest asking a new question. I won't be able to help I think.