# Disable formatting for a selection inside listing?

Tags: listings

I am typesetting my MATLAB code with package `matlab-prettifier`, which is essentially `listing`. However, sometimes I do not want the formatting. I simply want pure unformatted text.

For example, in the MWE below, the word for is mistaken as a MATLAB command and thus typeset in blue. How do I have this line displayed in plain, unformatted text? **Meanwhile, I don't wish to lose the MATLAB formatting for other real MATLAB commands.**

## MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% For MATLAB code
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true,style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\mlttfamily\footnotesize]
>> str = 'I am doing this for nothing';
>> str
I am doing this for nothing.
\end{lstlisting} 

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: `\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true,basicstyle=\mlttfamily\footnotesize]
I am doing this for nothing.
\end{lstlisting}`.

Comment: The reason that `style=Matlab-editor` is specified as an option is so you don't have to use it on every listing... Omit it like Gonzalo showed.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am sorry but my MWE is actually wrong. In fact, I have a mixture of MATLAB code plus this plain text. I don't with to lose my MATLAB formatting either. Please see updated question.

Comment: @BenVoigt It is actually a mixture of MATLAB code and plain text. So simply removing the style, the MATLAB formatting will be lost too. See updated question. :)

Comment: Your content is from MATLAB's R-E-P-L rather than the editor, so it is expected that `matlab-editor` gives inappropriate results...  Maybe someday there will be a style for `matlab-repl`.

Comment: @FarticlePilter I've thought about ways of disabling highlighting on output lines of an interactive session. However, coming up with a robust solution for that is hard; you would probably need a full parser of the programming language in question, which is beyond what `listings` can do. Instead, why not simply separate input and output in different listings?

Comment: @Jubobs Separating them into 2 listings will lead to separate frames, won't it? That would be weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Disclaimer

What follows is a terrible and probably inefficient hack (like most of `matlab-prettifier`'s code, really). A half-decent implementation would require more careful thought. Use at your own peril; you've been warned `:)`

In particular, this approach has one big caveat: the second and subsequent lines of multiline commands won't get highlighted at all.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% For MATLAB code
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}


\makeatletter

% switch indicating whether a prompt was detected on the current line
\newif\ifprompt@mlpr@

% set the switch if a prompt was detected on the current line
\lstset{literate={>>}{{\processPrompt@mlpr}}2}
\newcommand\processPrompt@mlpr{%
  >{}>%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode\relax%
    \global\prompt@mlpr@true%
  \fi
}

% disable highlighting if a prompt was detected on the current line
\lst@AddToHook{Output}{\condDisableHiliting}
\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}{\condDisableHiliting}
\newcommand\condDisableHiliting{%
  \ifprompt@mlpr@%
  \else
    \let\lst@thestyle\lst@basicstyle%
  \fi
}

% reset the switch at the beginning of each "real" line
\lst@AddToHook{EveryPar}{\global\prompt@mlpr@false}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[%
  mathescape = true,
  style      = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle = \mlttfamily\footnotesize,
]
>> str = 'I am doing this for nothing';
>> str
I am doing this for nothing.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the color to black, like so:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{escapeinside={<@}{@>}}

% For MATLAB code
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true,style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\mlttfamily\footnotesize]
>> str = 'I am doing this for nothing';
>> str
<@\textcolor{black}{I am doing this for nothing.}@>
\end{lstlisting} 

\end{document}
```

from: [color a text line in a code {lstlisting}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144448/color-a-text-line-in-a-code-lstlisting)

It is a bit of a roundabout, but I do not see how you would otherwise escape text within the lstlisting environment.

Comment: This works, but not very elegantly. When the text chunk is huge, everything is screwed up by losing formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider simply adding the option `mlkeywordstyle=\color{black}` to the `lstlisting` environment. Your example would be

```
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true, style=Matlab-editor, basicstyle=\mlttfamily\footnotesize, mlkeywordstyle=\color{black}]
>> str = 'I am doing this for nothing';
>> str
I am doing this for nothing.
\end{lstlisting}
```

This works well if you have a small piece of code, with some command-line text understood as Matlab keywords.
[image]